# What kind of an impact does moving have on your credit (score)?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score

Being an international student, the room I rent near campus has been my domestic home address since I came here to study.

Now that I am working at a place quite far from campus, I would like to relocate.

It's been around 6 months since I opened up my first credit cards, and some of them are still cash secured.

I would like to know what kind of an impact could relocating have on my credit score.

1. Could it possibly be detremental and possibly negatively impact my cash secured cards from "maturing" to unsecured cards?
2. Could it possibly lead to me being turned down if I wanted to increase my credit lines or apply for a new loan (like a car loan, a new phone contract etc?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could it possibly be detrimental and possibly negatively impact my
>   cash secured cards from "maturing" to unsecured cards?

In theory moving could impact getting an unsecured card, but that is going to be if you move to a state where the company does not offer unsecured cards.  But if you are just looking to move off campus not out of state then this should not be an issue.

> Could it possibly lead to me being turned down if I wanted to increase
>   my credit lines or apply for a new loan (like a car loan, a new phone
>   contract etc?)

Moving itself will not affect this.  However moving creates expenses and opportunities to create debt.  Having more debt impacts your debt/income ratio.  That can impact your credit score(both positively and negatively).  So it can indirectly affect these but will not directly affect them.

Answer (score 3):

Your address has nothing to do with your credit score. It does appear on your credit report, but is used for verification purposes (it will come up once in a while in the questions you're being asked to verify your identity, for example when you open a bank account online).

Comment: Not true, volatile address history, as well as hotel, trailer (caravan) parks, and marina addresses are a red flag. Credit providers have in-house scorecards that penalise you for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that you have all accounts, cards, etc at the **same** address.   Otherwise provided you don't move every few months, moving should not be an issue.