# Changing credit address to apartment address

Tags: credit-card, credit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of an impact does moving have on your credit (score)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12911/what-kind-of-an-impact-does-moving-have-on-your-credit-score)

I recently moved out of my parents house into an apartment in the city, and I've noticed it's way easier to get credit when I apply using my parents' address, because I've applied for past credit cards and such at my old address; credit companies don't "know" anything about Kevin at my current address.

If I change address to my current address (for example in the Preferences page of all my credit cards), will my credit ratings transfer over? Like is there some way to tell the credit agencies that I've changed my address? Also I'm not sure how long I am going to stay in this apartment, maybe a year or two, but I could probably continue to get mail at my parents address for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Address appears on your credit report and is used for verification. Length of your period of residency at the current address is usually being asked for verification in the forms, and I guess has some influence in the decision making. Since you've just moved, that might be a negative point, which you don't get while using your parents' address.

That said, since you're using your SSN (I assume US) to identify yourself, you're matched perfectly, there are no "two different" Kevins here. You will be moving during your life, and it's OK.

You would be better off receiving your mail where you live and not at your parents, and you'd be better off with your current address appearing on your credit report.

Comment: +1, but you forgot that you answered exactly this a few months ago :-D

Comment: so it seems....